# Conditional expression of distinct Objective-C types lacks a cast?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I recieve this error:

Conditional expression of distinct Objective-C types 'struct NSNull *' and 'struct NSNMutableArray *' lacks a cast

On this line of code:

`( (tempArray != nil) ? tempArray : [NSNull null] )`

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two legs of the conditional expression are supposed to have the same datatype. Cast the first one to `id` to avoid the warning.

May I ask why do you need NSNull, and not `nil`?

Comment: Thanks! I want to add several arrays to another array, then serialize them for saving data.  If one is nil, it may cause a problem when loading the array back in, correct?

Comment: Yeah, I recall you cannot put a nil into an NSArray.